# Higher Order Component Types Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I am trying the following code. But the typescript error won't go away. Also, not sure whats the error even means.

```
type CounterProps = {
    counter: number
}

const WithCounter = <T extends CounterProps> (Component: React.ComponentType<T>) => {
    const ComponentWithCounter = (props: Omit<T, keyof CounterProps>) => {
        return <Component {...props} counter={23} />
    }
    return ComponentWithCounter
}
```

I am simply trying to inject a counter "number" props to my underlying component.
It is giving the following error.

```
Type 'Omit<T, "counter"> & { counter: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T'.
    Type 'Omit<T, "counter"> & { counter: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'Omit<T, "counter"> & { counter: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'CounterProps'.ts(2322)
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/hoc/full_example/). I did notice that over there they have done {...props as T} while passing them.. but I don't understand why we need to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours on this, came up with this solution instead.

```
interface CounterProps {
    counter: number;
}

const withCounter = <T extends {}> (Component: ComponentType<T & CounterProps>) => {
    const InnerComponent: React.FC<T> = (props) => {
        return <Component {...props} counter={23} />
    }

    return InnerComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your implementation `WithCounter` can be called as below.

```
type InvalidType = {counter: number, invalidProperty: unknown}
const input: React.ComponentType<InvalidType> = ...
WithCounter(input)
```

But since `InvalidType` isn't valid as input to `Component`, the error is shown.